# Problem with masks: why gradual decay shape always grows under Shift-scroll?

Tags: darktable

I have troubles understanding how to use masks in Darktable.

I'd like to adjust the difference between a mask and the corresponding gradual decay shape. However, when I Shift-scroll, the gradual decay shape always increases, no matter in which direction I scroll. This makes it impossible to use masks in Darktable for me.

Does anybody know how to decrease gradual decay shapes instead of increasing them?

I use Darktable 2.6.2 on macOS Catalina.